# Accessing Markdown PHP function from within a class

Tags: php, oop, markdown

I'm using the Markdown library for PHP by Michel Fortin. Setup is easy and it works great like this:

```
include_once "markdown.php";
$my_html = Markdown($my_text);
```

However, I have a class in which I want to pass stuff and 'Markdown' it, like so:

```
class Test
{
    public function showMarkdown ($text)
    {
        return Markdown($text);
    }
}
```

Obviously, my class is much larger than this, but this is what it boils down to. In my main script I do:

```
include_once "markdown.php";
$test = new Test();
echo $test->showMarkdown($text);
```

This returns an error, saying the function 'Markdown' is undefined. That seems obvious, because it's not within the class and I haven't used a scope operator. But when I put the include inside my class and use `$this->Markdown` or `self::Markdown` the function is still undefined. I figured that the Markdown function can't be defined inside another function.

So, how can I solve this? I need to do the include, which loads the Markdown function (and the rest of its family) but I want to be able to use it from within my classes.
Thanks for your answers/ideas.

Comment: Obviously php didn't load your markdown library, you should verify display_errors is on (or take a look at error log), and use require_once since your class needs this library to work

Comment: Actually, my complete class is not *that* dependent on the Markdown library, at least I don't want it to stop script execution (which require does). And the errors were there already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code calls a free function called `Markdown` (which presumably is defined in `markdown.php`). You simply need to put the include in the same file as your `Test` class.

After doing this, you will still call `Markdown` as a free function, and not as an instance (`$this->Markdown`) or static (`self::Markdown`) method.

Comment: That solved it, thanks! One extra question though: if I want to make loading Markdown conditional, let's say when somewhere in my class I would determine the need to load it, how would I load it then? Of course this is not necessary for it to work, but would save a bit of bandwidth...

Comment: @kasimir: Put the `include` just before you will use Markdown, and make it an `include_once` so that you won't load it multiple times (which would error out). But it won't save bandwidth, as including files has nothing to do with what is sent to the client.

Comment: @Downvoter: I 'm long past caring about drive-by downvotes, but sometimes they still baffle me.

Comment: you're right, it won't save bandwidth, perhaps only a tiny bit of server time. I think I'll keep it simple and just put it before the class definition so it's obvious.

Answer (score 0):

write

```
function showMarkdown ($text)
in place of
public function showMarkdown ($text)
```

and

```
echo $test->showMarkdown("Hello World");
```